# Fetch array and feed it to a variable inside a loop

Tags: php

In the following code I simple feed the values of the form

```
$t = $_GET['type'];
$p = $_GET['product'];
$b = $_GET['brand'];
$c = $_GET['category'];
$attribute = getattributes($p,$b,$c);
$count = count($attribute);
$i=0;
```

The variable $attribute has

```
Array([0]=>size [1]=>weight)
```

Now using the above array i want to generate the following lines

```
$size = $_GET['size'];
$weight = $_GET['weight'];
```

I don't want to assign manually just like the above but create the two lines using loops.

Something like

```
$i=0;
while($i < $count)
{
    '$'.$attribute[$i] = '$_GET['.$attribute[$i].']'; //edited part
}
```

I don't know if this will work, could somebody provide a simple piece of code to achieve the same?

**Solution Code:**

Awlad Liton: Thank for your answer. There is a minor change in your code which gave the desired output (value form the form)

```
foreach($attribute as $k => $v){
$$v = $_GET[$v];
}
```

Comment: Yes, the page keep loading after adding the above loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**
Demo: https://eval.in/96388

```
$attribute = array(0=>'size', 1=>'weight');
foreach($attribute as $k => $v){
    $$v = '$_GET['."'$v'".']';

}
echo $size." ";
echo $weight;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$_GET['size'] $_GET['weight']
```

**UPDATE:**
as you reply you can do this:

```
foreach($attribute as $k => $v){
  $$v = $_GET[$v];
}
```

Comment: @Ashik Basheer: i think you wanted this. Did you try this?

Comment: You were almost right Awlad. but the output prints $_GET[size] directly. What I wanted is the value. I made a simple change to your code and that works fine :) I'll update the code in my post now.

Comment: Accepted :) Is there a way to store them into array?

    Array([0]=>'value of size' [1]=>'value of weight')

Comment: it was array first.After all calculation you want it back again? you can do it  `array(0=>$size , 1 =>$weight)`

Answer (score 1):

you are almost right. try this:

```
$$attribute[$i] = $_GET[$attribute[$i]];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: are you kidding me? dreamweaver? - but my fault - remove the brackets - see above

Comment: This will not work until you have some query string as ?size=something&weight=something, else it will return undefined index error, so you must check the code in browser.